# Como fazer para recuperrar um dado com Select2 na edição do registro?

Tags: laravel-5, html-select, laravel-blade

Segue o código da blade, quando vou para o modo de edição o dado correspondente não aparece e sim a select2 fica em branco.

```
<select name="cliente_id">
         <option value=""></option>
           @foreach ($clientes as $cliente )
              <option name="cliente_id" value="{{$cliente->id}}" 
           @if(old('cliente_id')==$cliente->id) {{'selected'}} @endif>
              {{$cliente->nome}}
           @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

São dois pontos a serem observados:

1) Na Edição a atribuição com comparação utilizando old() tem de ser verificado via javascript usando `$(elemento).val();`

2) Se a condição acima estiver funcionando, após setar o valor via blade, provavelmente vc esta inicializando o select2, porém o campo ainda permanece em branco pois precisa "atualizar" o elemento porque quando vc iniciliza ele perde o atributo "selected" já que um novo componente é incorporado na tela, as é fácil de se resolver, basta executar um `$(elemento).trigger('change');` que irá funcionar;